# What is the difference between competent, material, and substantial evidence?

Tags: evidence, administrative-law

In Michigan, and perhaps in other states too, an appellate court will uphold the facts found by an administrative agency if the facts are supported by competent, material, and substantial evidence. What is the difference between competent evidence, material evidence, and substantial evidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Competent** evidence is admissible under the relevant rules of evidence for the tribunal.

**Material** evidence bears directly on a point that is in contention before the tribunal.

**Substantial** evidence is compelling in deciding the point.

Comment: Thank you. Can you add some authority?